# Which is correct, English is spoken by people in the US. or English is spoken in the US by people

Tags: grammar

Which is correct? or more natural?

1. English is spoken in the US by people.
2. English is spoken by people in the US.

I know in this case we could omit "by people." However, if we don't omit it, which is the correct position in the sentence?

Answer (score 5):

The first implies a very odd emphasis.

> English is spoken in the US by *people*, but dogs speak Spanish.

To be honest, neither of these sound very natural. You wouldn't really use the passive here at all. Rather you would say:

> People in the US speak English.

Comment: Without knowing the broader context for the sentence, we can't say if the passive voice is appropriate. For instance, if the passage is about the English language, not Americans, then it's probably a good idea to put "English" in subject position.

Answer (score 2):

They're both grammatically correct, but have different meanings.

The first sentence roughly means, "In the US, English is spoken by humans."

The second sentence roughly means, "English is spoken by Americans."

Comment: Wow, thank you. Then what if I change the sentence into: English is spoken in many places by people. VS English is spoken by people in many places. ---Do they also imply the meanings as you mentioned above?

Comment: They might have, but there is a further possible interpretation: the second might be parsed as _English is spoken by [people in many places]_, (which is actually the most natural interpretation). This is different from _English is [spoken by people] [in many places]_, which as gotube indicated suggests that in other places it is spoken by non-people.